# How can I disable file auto-refresh in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code seems to auto-refresh an open unchanged file when the file is changed externally.  This seems to cause VS code to be very slow, even non-responsive, when I open a file having a lot of external activity, such as a log file.  When this happens VS Code looks to have high CPU usage.  Is there a way to disable file auto-refresh in VS Code and only refresh the file manually via **File** -> **Revert File**?  I'm running VS code 1.87.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.6.

Comment: I'll try to check today and revert you back. But one question. If you have file open in your VC then it will get refreshed but if it's not then VS Code should not behave that way. If it is doing so then probably you need to clear cache and maybe reinstall vs code or delete temp files, especially associated with it.

Comment: The file is getting refreshed in VS Code.  The problem is that VS Code is very slow to respond.  If I close the file in VS Code, VS Code then starts responding just fine as usual.

Comment: Buddy, the file will get refreshed in that scenario because vs code is synced with version control system of our project repository.